# Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Tags: symfony

i want to create an evaluation entity in the classe FicheController , so i used

```
use Polytech\SkillsBundle\Entity\SousOccasion;
use Polytech\SkillsBundle\Entity\Evaluation;
use Polytech\SkillsBundle\Entity\EvaluationCompetence;
.....
```

and then :

```
 $evaluation = new Evaluation();
```

but i get this error

```
Attempted to load class "Evaluation" from namespace "Polytech\SkillsBundle\Controller".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

Comment: What namespaces do `Evaluation` and `FicheController` belong to?

Comment: FicheController belong to namespace Polytech\SkillsBundle\Controller;
Evaluation belong to ue Polytech\SkillsBundle\Entity

Comment: Can you show your Evaluation class? Check for spelling errors, especially in the class name.

Comment: I found my error : i forgot to call another entity which will be inserted in the evaluation object !

Comment: @AmiraKhalifa What does that mean? Can you post an answer of what you did? I am running into the same issue but I have been stumped for 2 days on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try $evaluation = new Polytech\SkillsBundle\Entity\Evaluation();

Comment: You missed the leading slash.